# Methodology for interprocess communication

Tags: vb.net, text-files, ipc, methodology, inter-process-communicat

I'm planning on developing a Monopoly game using a Console application in VB.NET, but with a separate GUI (probably a Forms application) that displays the state of the Monopoly board based on the information in the Console application, so that it can be ignored or used as the players wish. I've been looking into ways of sending information between two programs, and came across Pipes, except they seem complex and I'd like to use a different method if I can avoid it. The following is the methodology I'm currently considering to send information - I'd like to know if there is any way I could improve this methodology, or if you think it's completely stupid and I should just use Pipes instead -

Program 1 is the Console application which controls everything: the state of the game depends on the Console. Program 2 is the GUI/Forms application which follows instructions sent by Program 1 and displays the board accordingly. Program 1 and Program 2 communicate using two text files, Command.txt and CommandAvailable.txt. When something changes on Program 1 - e.g. a player makes a move - a command string is made and added to a queue. Program 1 continually checks CommandAvailable.txt to ensure that the file is *empty*, and if so, it clears Command.txt and then appends every command string in the queue to Command.txt. When it has finished, arbitrary text is added to CommandAvailable.txt, e.g. "CommandAvailable".

Program 2 continually checks CommandAvailable.txt until it is *not empty*, meaning that Program 1 has added at least one command to Command.txt. Program 2 then reads every instruction on Command.txt and adds it onto a queue on the other side. CommandAvaiable.txt is then cleared, which will permit Program 1 to add more Commands to Command.txt (because it only adds commands when CommandAvailable.txt is empty and hasn't already been marked by itself.) A separate thread on Program 2 empties the queue of command strings, parses them and executes them.

For example, in the Console, Player 1 may move to Trafalgar Square (or whatever the square would be called.) Program 1/Console would add the Command "move player1 trafalgar_square" to the queue, then check CommandAvailable.txt, and if it is empty, add all the commands in the queue to Command.txt. Program 2/The GUI would check CommandAvailable.txt and as it had been marked by Program 1, read the command, add it to the queue, and then move a picturebox that represents Player 1 to a square.

Please let me know if you think this methodology could be improved, or if you think it's simply stupid and there are far better alternatives or that I should just use Pipes instead. I'm going to be using VB.NET.

Comment: The standard recommended technology for inter-process communication in .NET is WCF.

Comment: You could use [Pipes](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=871044), or [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) (what I'd go with), or queueing services like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or anything, really, except writing commands to text files for passing data between your processes.